# How to prevent Wi-Fi from going to sleep? (via Terminal)

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, terminal, mac, wifi

When Im not using the laptop, after a few min, the screen will dim. Returning after >15 min and waking the laptop, the wifi needs to reconnect to my wifi hotspot. **How can I keep wifi connected indefinitely using Terminal?**

Some related articles that I didnt find helpful:

[Prevent iMac from sleeping, for VPN login?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44955/prevent-imac-from-sleeping-for-vpn-login)

[Prevent MacBook Pro from going to sleep](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33868/prevent-macbook-pro-from-going-to-sleep)

```
$ pmset -g
System-wide power settings:
Currently in use:
 standbydelay         4200
 standby              1
 halfdim              1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 powernap             0
 disksleep            10
 sleep                10
 autopoweroffdelay    28800
 hibernatemode        3
 autopoweroff         1
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         1
 acwake               0
 lidwake              1

sh-3.2# system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType 
Software:

    System Software Overview:

      System Version: macOS 10.13.4 (17E199)
      Kernel Version: Darwin 17.5.0
      Boot Volume: lily
      Boot Mode: Normal
      Computer Name: lily’s MacBook Air
      User Name: System Administrator (root)
      Secure Virtual Memory: Enabled
      System Integrity Protection: Enabled
      Time since boot: 2:03
```

Comment: So ... the MB Air (you don't specify what specific model) loses its Wi-Fi connection, but it does not go to sleep? This is not normal behavior, and is indicative of faulty software, faulty hardware, or both. No amount of hand waving (terminal commands) will be able to fix this. I suggest reinstalling macOS.

Comment: Is the laptop still awake (IOW, please clarify "idle for a few mins")?  Are you on AC power or battery?  What are your power settings (`pmset -g`)?

Comment: @IconDaemon @Allan hey guys, i tried to better explain the issue and also included the `pmset -g` output

Comment: I would bet that's it's happening after 10 mins.  You still didn't if you were on battery or plugged in, but from the looks of things, you are on battery.  This is normal behavior.